# User Authentication Failed on CreateEnvelope

Tags: docusignapi

I encountered a new issue today when I tried to send a request with my new production account and the integrator key, newly promoted to Live status.

The API login succeeded, and it returns my AccountID.

However, when I try to create an envelope with envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope API call, I received the following error.

I tested the code with my demo account and key, couple of days ago. It was working fine. I think it is related to the key, because the login request was succeed.

```
DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: 'Error calling CreateEnvelope: {    
  "errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",    
  "message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid."    
}
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I need to do.

Answer (score 3):

Often when the `USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` error is received and you are positive the correct user/pwd combo is being provided it's because of the wrong account endpoint being accessed.

You need to parse sub-domain of the `baseUrl` that is returned from the Login API (property is called `base_uri` if using OAuth2) and configure your api client with that sub-domain.

When testing in demo it's ok if you miss this step since all accounts are under the `demo.docusign.net` sub-domain, however in production there are multiple sub-domains (ie. www, na2, eu, etc) so you need to re-configure once right after authentication.

---

Example:

The response to the [Authentication: login](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Authentication/Authentication/login/) API looks like:

```
{
    "loginAccounts": [
        {
            "accountId": "123456",
            "baseUrl": "https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/123456",
            "email": "jdoe@example.com",
            "isDefault": "true",
            "name": "LoanCo",
            "siteDescription": "",
            "userId": "abcdff66-f92e-4e8e-ab81-8c46f140",
            "userName": "John Doe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then instantiate a new API client using the sub-domain that was returned in the login response:

```
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://na2.docusign.net");
```